# Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied

Tags: vpn, iptables

I have just subscribed for a VPN service and while I did notice that at times the connection drops, I looked around for ways to setup a kill-switch in Ubuntu.
I did follow the instructions at https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-vpn-killswitch-using-iptables-on-linux
but am getting the following issues (my VPN is setup to OpenVPN):

- When running `sysctl -p` I get the following output:

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl -p
  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
  net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
  sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
  ```
- When it comes to flushing the current IP tables, I get the error:

  ```
  Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied
  ```

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: List your network devices: `ip link`. Tell us which item on the list is the one that connects to the VPN.

Comment: You question should explain exactly what command you use for "flushing the current IP tables". Show us complete input and output.

Comment: tun0 is what my VPN connects to.
iptables -F && iptables -X is the command I'm using to flush. Got it from the linked guide.

Comment: FYI, Gnome has an excellent built-in VPN client...including routing control and a kill switch.

Comment: Pls tell me more about the built-in VPN client in Gnome.

Answer (score 2):

1. `No such file or directory` is easy to troubleshoot - just look in your own filesystem. In this case, it's not `eth0`. It's your actual network connection (likely something like `tun_` or `enp___` or `wlp___`).
2. `Permission denied` is also an easy one - it means you forgot to use `sudo`.

Comment: Changed eth0 to tun0 and sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6: No such             
 file or directory is solved.

Have tried sudo but "Permission Denied" error persists

Comment: Apologies. The error I was getting, "sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6: No such             
 file or directory" when running the command, "sudo sysctl -p" was solved by changing eth0 to tun0 as per your suggestion above.

Comment: However, the error, "Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied" when trying to flush IP tables is persistent in spite of using the sudo command, "sudo iptables -F && iptables -X"

Answer (score 0):

`sudo iptables -F && iptables -X` should be `sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -X`.  The second `iptables` (the `-X` one) won't be run as root otherwise and you'll have permission problems with the `xtables.lock`.

FYI the `xtables` thing is a common program called `xtables-nft-multi` that nowadays does various `iptables` functions by looking at which name it was invoked under.  It's not well thought of in some circles.